# Time offset calculation is off by one minute

Tags: c++, datetime, visual-c++, timezone

I am trying to replace a number of different time classes with a single consistent API. However I have recently run into a problem whereby I cannot serialise the timezone offset correctly. Note that I am attempting to replicate an existing format that is already in wide use in the system.

The format should be `YYYY-mm-DD HH:MM:SS.xxxxxxx -HHMM`, where the `x` represents the sub-second precision and the last `-HHMM` is the TZ offset from UTC.

**Code**:

```
using namespace My::Time;
namespace chrn = std::chrono;
time_point now = clock::now();
time_point lclNow = getDefaultCalendarProvider()->toLocal(now);
duration diff{ lclNow - now };
std::wstring sign = diff > duration::zero() ? L" +" : L" -";
duration ms{ now.time_since_epoch().count() % duration::period::den };
int diffHrs = popDurationPart<chrn::hours>(diff).count();
int diffMins{ abs(chrn::duration_cast<chrn::minutes>(diff).count()) };
std::cout << Format{ lclNow, TimeZone::UTC, L" %Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S." } << ms.count()
    << sign << std::setfill(L'0') << std::setw(2) << diffHrs
    << std::setfill(L'0') << std::setw(2) << diffMins << std::endl;
```

**Problem**:

> Expected:<2016-05-25 09:45:18.1970000 +0100> Actual:< 2016-05-25
>   09:45:18.1964787 +0059>

The expected value is what you get when I use the old class to do the same operation. The problem appears to be at the point where I attempt to get the difference between `lclNow` and `now`.

Currently I am in UTC +1 (due to DST being in effect). However the `diff` value is always `35999995635`. Being on Visual C++ in Windows the tick is 100 ns, so there are 10000000 ticks per second, meaning the `diff` value is 3599.9995 seconds, which is just short of the 3600 seconds I would need to make an hour.

When I print the two time values using the same format then I can see that they are exactly one hour apart. So it appears that the time-zone translation is not the issue.

Comment: In the 1400+ pages that comprise the current C++ standard, there's no mention to anything that's called "getDefaultCalendarProvider()". As such, this must be some non-standard library function that implements some unspecified logic. You should look there for the answer to your question.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Thanks. Yes it looks like that is the problem, became apparent almost immediately after I posted the question. I'm gonna delete this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue appears to have come from the time-zone conversions as I was attempting (as SamVarshavchik pointed out). Unfortunately I am unable to use Howard Hinnant's very complete [date and tz libraries](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) because they require a mechanism to update the IANA time-zone DB that is required for them to work, so I resorted to wrapping the Windows native calls for the time-zone conversions; namely the [TzSpecificLocalTimeToSystemTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725485%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724949(v=vs.85).aspx) functions.

However these only work with [SYSTEMTIME](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724950(v=vs.85).aspx) and not `time_point`. This meant I took the quick and easy option of converting the `time_point` to a `FILETIME` (just modify the "epoch") and the `FILETIME` to a `SYSTEMTIME` before passing it to one of the two above functions. This resulted in truncation of the time value when it was pushed into the `SYSTEMTIME` struct (which only holds millisecond resolution). The outcome is that while I was accurate for dates, I was not entirely accurate when converting the date back into the original value.

The new solution does no calendar mapping for the basic `time_point` to `time_point` translations. It uses the following code to work out the offset in `std::chrono::minutes` (where `zoneInfo` is a [TIME_ZONE_INFORMATION](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms725481(v=vs.85).aspx)):

```
time_point WindowsTzDateProvider::doToUtc(const time_point& inLocal) const {
    return inLocal + getBias(inLocal);
}

time_point WindowsTzDateProvider::doToLocal(const time_point& inUtc) const {
    return inUtc - getBias(inUtc);
}

std::chrono::minutes WindowsTzDateProvider::doGetBias(const time_point& input) const {
    bool isDst = CalendarDateProvider::isDstInEffect(input);
    minutes baseBias{ zoneInfo.Bias };
    minutes extraBias{ isDst ? zoneInfo.DaylightBias : zoneInfo.StandardBias };
    return baseBias + extraBias;
}

bool CalendarDateProvider::isDstInEffect(const time_point& t) {
    time_t epochTime = clock::to_time_t(t);
    tm out;
#ifdef WIN32
    localtime_s(&out, &epochTime);
#else
    localtime_r(&out, &epochTime);
#endif
    return out.tm_isdst > 0;
}
```

Note: I'm using the non-virtual interface idiom for the classes, hence the "do..." versions of the methods.

Answer (score 2):

Consider using this [free, open source time zone library](https://github.com/HowardHinnant/date) which does exactly what you want with very simple syntax, and works on VS-2013 and later:

```
#include "tz.h"
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    using namespace date;
    using namespace std::chrono;
    auto t = make_zoned(current_zone(), system_clock::now());
    std::cout << format("%F %T %z", t) << '\n';
}
```

This should output for you:

```
2016-05-25 09:45:18.1970000 +0100
```

### C++20 update

This library is now part of C++20 `<chrono>` and ships with MSVC.  The syntax is slightly changed from that shown above:

```
#include <chrono>
#include <format>
#include <iostream>

int
main()
{
    std::chrono::zoned_time t{std::chrono::current_zone(), 
                              std::chrono::system_clock::now()};
    std::cout << std::format("{:%F %T %z}", t) << '\n';
}
```

[Demo](https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/sjGdvfa9E)

Comment: Thanks Howard... I'm aware of and very interested in your two libs (date2 and tz). Unfortunately I want to take advantage of windows registry based TZ info. I know you ship the IANA DB but that would be a bit of hassle and it would also require an update path.